# Empty row shown in list view with sections in Android in react native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

I have a list of things that I show in a list view with sections. I can add a new item by going to 'Add new item' screen. After the item is saved, I pop one screen and the user lands on the list view again. On this view, I see an empty in some cases as shown below.

[image]

One case where I always see an empty row is when I don't have any items in the `Recent` section and then I add an item which falls in `Recent` section. In this case, I always see an empty row on the `Past` Section as shown in the image.

The empty row disappears as soon as I scroll or do anything on the screen. I tried to use `RecyclerViewBackedScrollView` as the scroll component for the list view which solves this problem but that component is riddled with many other bugs and my app crashes a lot while using it.

I don't this caused by any incorrect code within my app. Below is how I create the `ListView`

```
<ListView
    dataSource={tempDataSource}
    renderRow={this.renderRow}
    renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
    renderSeparator={this.renderSeparator}
    style={styles.componentListViewContainer}
    initialSize={10}
    pageSize={10}
/>
```

I have confirmed that the `dataSource` doesn't contain any empty entry in there. `renderRow` renders the row, `renderSeparator` renders the horizontal lines, `renderSectionHeader` renders the `Recent` and the `Past` section headers.

I am using react-native `0.37.2` at the moment.

Please share if you have any information on how to fix this problem.

Comment: Please provide the code you think caused that error.

Comment: @AnnaMelzer I am not sure if there is any offending code within my app. I have posted how I am creating the sectioned list view in my question.